Image(uiImage:) converts colored image to black and white
I have a data object that dynamically changes the UIImage assigned to one of its instance variables, but when showing this image in SwiftUI, it's always black and white. The following sample code shows the difference between the same image, but using first the native constructor Image(systemName:) and then Image(uiImage:).
When using AppKit and Image(nsImage:) this issue doesn't happen.

import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var object = MyObject()
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle.fill")
            .symbolRenderingMode(.palette)
            .foregroundStyle(.white, .yellow)
        Image(uiImage: object.image)
    }
}

class MyObject {
    var image = UIImage(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle.fill")!
        .applyingSymbolConfiguration(.init(paletteColors: [.white, .systemYellow]))!
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


Interesting problem! I played around with this for a bit, and I'm not sure why, but it doesn't seem to be a supported behavior.
Is it possible / have you considered updating your object to dynamically provide the values that could be read by your SwiftUI view -- rather than providing an entire UIImage?

Do you mean that the data object should hold not the image itself but the image name? That would be a good solution, but the data object represents a file and the image the file icon, which is retrieved via the file URL. When the file is not available, or hasn't been selected yet, I then resort to different system images.

Yes! If you're dynamically fetching content and falling back to a system symbol when that fails, this sounds like a good use case for an enum with associated values. You could then switch in your SwiftUI view and display either the custom file icon or the symbol. Alternatively, you could just import SwiftUI in your MyObject class and return an Image instead of a UIImage.

Thanks, that's a good idea! I ended up writing a custom view that returns the native SwiftUI image based on the state of the data object.

From the docs:

For this color configuration to have an effect, your symbol image must have the following:
Its renderingMode set to UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysTemplate or UIImage.RenderingMode.automatic.

FYI Using classes like UIImage with @State required special handling as follows:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var image: UImage? // we cannot init classes inline here, it's a memory leak.
    
    var body: some View { 
        Group {
            if let image {
                Image(uiImage: image)
                .onDisappear {
                    image = nil
                }
            }
            else {
                Text("Loading Image")
                .onAppear {
                    image = UIImage(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle.fill")!
                 }
            }
         }
    }
}

Try and stick to Swift struct or value types with @State wherever you can to avoid this problem.

This doesn't answer why the image is black and white in my code.

@State var should be @State private var

I don't see your code using the renderingMode at all. That setting doesn't change anything when used in my code.
